# Handling reCaptcha forms?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple program that logs on to a site, does something and logs out. The problem is that the login form has three inputs: username, password and a recaptcha. I input all of them manually. The problem is I don't know how to display the captcha image or how to send the text.

Can someone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It is unreasonable to except that someone will post a complete solution for your problem.
Here are the steps, just start by trying to complete them, post questions if you get stuck.
very generally speaking:

1. Get the content of the site (use the `urllib2` to fetch the page)
2. Parse the recaptcha image link and download the image (`BeautifulSoup` for parsing the link, `urllib2` again for downloading the image)
3. prompt yourself with the image and input for the code (use `Tkinter` for example)
4. send login info & captcha( `urllib2`)
5. do stuff (`urllib2` again)

There's probably some token that you also have to fetch that identifies your Captcha image. Use firebug to watch for the requests sent when submitting the Captcha.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll do it like that - sounds like it's the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html

look to this link :: it explains how to use recaptcha for several languages ..

i used it in my asp.net application...

i don't know how to use it in python

Comment: You got me wrong, I'm trying to somehow solve an existing captcha, not to put a new one.

Comment: You ever implemented this, found a solution?